# Tengo problemas para hacer funcionar mi codigo, ya que no me toma la recursion:

Tags: recursión

Secuencia inventada: f(n) = (f(n-1) + f(n-2) + f(n-3)) x 2
Donde las primeras tres posiciones son dadas por el array recibido por parametro y a partir de
la siguiente se calcula como la suma de los 3 números anteriores multiplicados por dos.
array es un arreglo de 3 posiciones que puede contener números o strings, aquellas posiciones que
sean números debemos dejarlas tal cual están pero las que tengan strings debemos calcular su cantidad
de caracteres para usarlos en la secuencia. //length
Por ejemplo si recibimos: ["Franco", 1, "Henry"] deberíamos tener los siguientes 3 valores iniciales
de la secuencia f(0) = 6, f(1) = 1 y f(2) = 5 (Ya que "Franco" tiene 6 caracteres y "Henry", 5)
A partir de ahí la cuarta posición sería  (6 + 1 + 5) * 2 = 24 y así sucesivamente
La función secuenciaHenr debe devolver el enésimo numero de la serie, por ejemplo para el arra
antes mencionado:
secuencia: 6, 1, 5, 24, 60, 178, 524
secuenciaHenr(0) // 6  ya que el elemento de la posición 0 es cero
secuenciaHenr(1) // 1 ya que el elemento de la posición 1 es 1
secuenciaHenr(6) // 524 ya que el elemento de la posición 6 es 524
Para números negativos de n debe devolver false

```
function secuenciaHenry(array, n) {
```

esto es lo que eh echo pero no logro hacerlo funcionar de la manera correcta.

```
let aux = 0
  if(n < 0) return false;
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(typeof array[i] === "string"){
      aux = array[i].length;
    } else {
      return (secuenciaHenry (array, n - 1)+secuenciaHenry(array, n - 2) + secuenciaHenry(array, n - 3))*2
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregar la condición de parada en la recursión, que ocurre cuando `n < 3` . Quedaría:

```js
function secuenciaHenry(array, n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return false;
    }


    const numbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (typeof array[i] === 'string') {
            numbers.push(array[i].length);
        } else {
            numbers.push(array[i]);
        }
    }


    if (n < 3) {
        return numbers[n];
    }

    return 2 * (secuenciaHenry(numbers, n - 1) + secuenciaHenry(numbers, n - 2) + secuenciaHenry(numbers, n - 3));
}




// Probando la funcion
const array = ["Rubien", 1, 5]
for (let i = -2; i < 7; i++) {
    console.log(`secuenciaHenry(${JSON.stringify(array)}, ${i}) = ${secuenciaHenry(array, i)}`);
}
```

Comment: Podrias explicarme la linea del map ?

Comment: @LuchoMuga Ahí lo coloqué sin el `map` para que lo entendieras mejor.